# How do I access an object by a generated instance name?

Tags: objective-c

I have an xib file with a number of views. Their `IBOutlet`s are named `view1`, `view2`, `view3`, and so on, and I want to access them in a loop. Is it possible to do this in Objective-C?

I know in ActionScript you can generate an object's name like this:  `["view"+num]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use key value coding. If say suppose I have view1 .. view 10, then I would use it like this;

```
for(int i=0 i< 10; i++){
  UIView *eachView = [self valueForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"view%d", i]];
}
```

I hope it works for you.

Comment: This works quite well. I would suggest this too.

Answer (score 3):

Put them in an IBOutletCollection. This is an array, you can populate it in interface builder and iterate through it.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than naming them, assign them tags (0...10) then you can pull them out of the parent view with `viewWithTag:`.

Answer (score 0):

Another way you can accomplish this is using [`NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Miscellaneous/AppKit_Functions/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/macro/NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings).

```
NSArray *views = [NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(view1, view2, view3) allObjects];
for (UIView *item in views)
    do something with item;
```